# Error when using postgresql with pgOleDb provider and long string parameter

Tags: postgresql, oledb

I'm using postgresql with pgOleDb provider. When i try to execute query where wone of the parameters longer than 35 symbols (i'm using utf-8), i recive this error

```
ERROR:  identifier too long
DETAIL:  Identifier must be less than 64 characters.
```

There is no problems when running this query with Ado.Net provider from devart. How can i solve it?

Provider from this site:  http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched proveder to official ODBC http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit old now, but I could not solve this using ADO components so used ZEOS components successfully